# Trying to use a JSON object as a argument (Python)

Tags: python, json, testing, parameters, arguments

I've written some code that converts a JSON object to an iCalendar (.ics) object and now I am trying to test it.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to create a generic JSON object to use as the parameter. Some of my attempts are as follows:

```
# 1
obj_json = u'sample json data in string form'
obj = json.loads(obj_json)

# 2
# I'm not sure about this very first line. My supervisor told me to put it in but he
# has a very heavy accent so I definitely could have heard him incorrectly.
input.json
with open('input.json') as f:
    obj = json.loads(f.read())
```

Comment: Both of those should work (except the first line of the second one, unless you changed the built-in `input` object). What's wrong with them?

Comment: I figured that first line had to be wrong. It says that input.json doesn't exist. I'm not sure I understand what you're saying to change it to though.

Comment: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.json'

Comment: Well, obviously it won't work if the file you're trying to read from doesn't exist.

Comment: I understand that, but how can I create basically a "dummy" JSON object to test this code??

Comment: You could load from a string like in your first example.

Comment: as python converts json to dict, you can create dummy object like this: **obj={}**; or dummy json string like this: **obj_json = u'{}'**. For your second sample, if loading fails, you will still have dummy dict in **obj**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
import json

some_dict = {'id': 0123, 'text': 'A dummy text'}

dummy_json = json.dumps(some_dict)
```

Now, feed your dummy json to your function. i.e.

```
'{"text": "A dummy text", "id": 83}'
```

You can do dumps with a string object too.

Answer (score 0):

See pnv's answer, but you probably don't need to dump it.  Just use a dictionary, as pnv did, and pass that into whatever you need to.  Unless you are about to pass your json object over the wire to something, I don't know why you'd want to dump it.

I would've added this as a comment, but no rep, yet.  :)